# Python Subprocess Popen with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I use ffmpeg for converting some videos.
I am calling command with subprocess.Popen(...)

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

self.my_pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
startupinfo=si)

(output, error) = self.my_pro.communicate()
```

and i kill with this method

```
self.my_pro.kill()
```

It's okey without compile to exe.

But i compiled with `pyinstaller` with `--noconsole` subprocess not working.
I must change `subprocess.Popen(...)` to `subprocess.check_output(...)`

But this time i can't kill process with `self.my_pro.kill()` this not working.

How i can run process with i can kill and it will run pyinstaller noconsole?

Comment: if `check_output()` works but `Popen() + .communicate()` doesn't then the issue is your code that uses `Popen()` because `check_output()` is implemented on top of `Popen()` internally. Have you tried to [redirect everything (stdin,stderr,stdout)](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess)?

Answer (score 3):

As @jfs wrote, with `Popen` you have to redirect everything. You forgot `stdout`

So this code doesn't crash for me anymore:

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

self.my_pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
startupinfo=si)
```