# PyInstaller subprocess.checkout error

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I developing a GUI app in Python, the code works fine in PyCharm IDE. Now I want to convert into an exe for distribution.

My code works fine until I generate a single file exe with PyInstaller with -w option enable (command: pyinstaller -F -w ). If I omit -w option, the code works fine but the final exe shows unwanted console as well.

To find a solution, I searched and found this to be a suitable workaround:

[Python Subprocess Popen with Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020644/python-subprocess-popen-with-pyinstaller)

Therefore, I tried Recipe sub-process as described here:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess

However, this is not working for me and I still get the error where subprocess command fails.

Anybody been in this situation, please help.
I am using Python 3.5, PyInstaller version 3.2.1.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - can you give an example of how you are trying to implement the fix? I can't get the fix to work either.